# JPA BigInteger and Long issue

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, long-integer, biginteger

I have a piece of code like this:

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Offer> query = cb.createQuery(Offer.class);
Root<Offer> root = query.from(Offer.class);
query = query.select(root).where(cb.equal(root.get(Offer_.companyID), company.getId()));
return em.createQuery(query).getResultList()
```

Now, this looks nice and dandy, but it gives me problems. Both offer.companyID and company.id are long.

Here's the what log shows me that hibernate is doing:

```
 Hibernate: SELECT C.id FROM company C INNER JOIN company_operators cm
 ON cm.company_id = c.id WHERE cm.operators_id = '503'
```

And this is the error I get:

```
12:47:00,581 ERROR [org.jboss.ejb3.invocation] (http--0.0.0.0-9080-5) JBAS014134: EJB Invocation failed on component OfferRepository for method public java.util.List org.jboss.tools.example.richfaces.data.OfferRepository.getOffersbyMemberId(java.lang.Long) throws java.lang.Exception: javax.ejb.EJBException: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.math.BigInteger cannot be cast to java.lang.Long
```

What could be the problem here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I think I have found the answer.

One line above the code I have shown was

```
Company company = companyRepo.getUsersCompany(memberId);
```

Hence, company.getId() in my query was fetching company entity from postgresql. And in that process, it cast id into 'BigInteger', implicitly.

So what I had to do was explicit cast to Long, and now my method looks like this:

```
    Company company = companyRepo.getUsersCompany(memberId);
    if (company == null) return null;
    CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<Offer> query = cb.createQuery(Offer.class);
    Root<Offer> root = query.from(Offer.class);
    Long companyId = company.getId();
    query = query.select(root).where(cb.equal(root.get(Offer_.companyID), companyId));
    return em.createQuery(query).getResultList();
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what type you have specified in your entity and in what is in table column.
It must be same. Check if both are same.

Comment: They should be, but they are not. In all entities I use Long as id.

Answer (score 0):

In your entity, you have `Long` for the numbers. You need to change those into `BigInteger`. Your JPA is returning you `BigInteger`.

Change these things like below:

```
private Long id;
```

with

```
private BigInteger id;
```

Comment: Thanks. Do you know why is JPA returning BigInteger and can it be avoided?

Comment: I don't know why. I have an application(created using JDeveloper) for Weblogic it was using `Long`, but when I created the same application again(with another version of JDeveloper), it gave me `BigInteger`. Database was oracle. I can suspect it can be the issue of JPA version. Or we may need to change something in configuration in somewhere! But I am not confirmed in this.

Comment: Seems like JPA imlicitly casts stuff to what it thinks it is.